# How can I rewrite selectively in Coq?

Tags: coq

```
a : nat
fvs : list nat
H : a = max (maxNum fvs) a + 1
H1 : max (maxNum fvs) a >= a
```

Doing `rewrite H in H1.`, replaces both the `a`s whereas I only want to rewrite the a on the RHS. Can it be done? I want to prove false from the above two hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `rewrite ... at <position>.` like so:

```
rewrite H in H1 at 2.
```

What you want can also be done in a slightly different way. Observe that `max (maxNum fvs) a` is irrelevant here -- you can use any natural number instead of that expression and your theorem would still hold. That means you can use the `generalize` tactic.

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Section foo.

  Variable a : nat.
  Variable fvs : list nat.
  Variable maxNum : list nat -> nat.
  Hypothesis H : a = max (maxNum fvs) a + 1.
  Hypothesis H1 : max (maxNum fvs) a >= a.

  Goal False.
    revert H H1; generalize (max (maxNum fvs) a) as n.
    intros n ->; rewrite Nat.add_1_r.
    apply Nat.nle_succ_diag_l.
  Qed.

End foo.
```